# An integrable and periodic function $f(x)$ satisfies $\int_{0}^{T}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)dx$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, periodic-functions

I want to prove:

> For an integrable function $f(x)$ and periodic with period $T$, for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $$\int_{0}^{T}f(x)\;dx=\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)\;dx.$$

I tried to change the values and define $y=a+x$ so that $dy=dx$ and the limits of the integrals are as we want, but I'm not sure how to use the fact that $f(x)$ is periodic.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dear Jozef: The simplest, I think, is to do the computation by using a primitive (or anti-derivative) $F$ of $f$. (At the end you can make $F$ disappear.) Also, compute "LHS minus RHS".

Comment: Let $N$ be such integer that $N\cdot T \in \langle a,a+T \rangle$. Does dividing the integral as $\int_a^{a+T}=\int_a^{NT}+\int_{NT}^{a+T}$ help?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If $F$ is a primitive of $f$, then

$$\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)\ dx-\int_{0}^{T}f(x)\ dx$$
$$=F(a+T)-F(a)-F(T)+F(0)$$
$$=\Big(F(a+T)-F(T)\Big)-\Big(F(a)-F(0)\Big)$$
$$=\int_T^{a+T}f(x)\ dx-\int_0^af(x)\ dx$$
$$=0.$$

One checks the last equality by making the obvious change of variable, and by using the periodicity.

**EDIT 1.** What I wrote above is how I *remember* the computation. Of course, it can be *written* like that:
$$
\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)\ dx-\int_{0}^{T}f(x)\ dx=\int_T^{a+T}f(x)\ dx-\int_0^af(x)\ dx=0.
$$

**EDIT 2.** Formal justification of the first equality in the above display:
$$
\int_0^af(x)\ dx+\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)\ dx=\int_{0}^{T}f(x)\ dx+\int_T^{a+T}f(x)\ dx.
$$

(This formula *should* appear somewhere...)

Comment: Dear @Jozef: You're most welcome!

Comment: Thank you @Pierre-YvesGaillard

Answer (score 29):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^{a+T}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^{T}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\left(\color{red}{\int_a^{T}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}+\int_T^{a+T}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&-\left(\int_0^{a}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\color{red}{\int_a^{T}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}\right)\\
&=\int_T^{a+T}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^{a}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{a}f(x+T)\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^{a}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{a}(f(x+T)-f(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{a}0\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Very nice!! But why $\int_0^{a}0\,\mathrm{d}x=0$ ? It should be a constant (call it $k$)

Comment: @Dor: The limits make that a [definite integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral). You are thinking of an indefinite integral or [anti-derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative).

Comment: @Dor $\int_0^a0dx=[k]_0^a=k-k=0$

Answer (score 12):

$\int_a^{a+T}f(t)dt=\int_a^Tf(t)dt+\int_T^{a+T}f(t)dt,$
and in the last integral, making the substitution $x=t-T$, we get for $a\in [0,T)$, since $f$ is $T$-periodic 
$$\int_a^{a+T}f(t)dt=\int_a^Tf(t)dt+\int_0^{a}f(x+T)dx=\int_a^Tf(t)dt+\int_0^{a}f(x)dx=\int_0^T f(t)dt.$$
For $a\in\mathbb R$, take $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $a+nT\in [0,T)$. Then 
$$\int_a^{a+T}f(t)dt=\int_{a+nT}^{a+(n+1)T}f(x-nT)dx=\int_{a+nT}^{a+(n+1)T}f(x)dx=\int_0^Tf(t)dt$$
using the previous case.

Comment: If I did not miss something, this works for $a\in \langle 0,T \rangle$, but general idea is basically the same.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, I have added the details. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! very helpful!

Answer (score 12):

Here's a picture illustrating the basic idea. (Compare the areas marked with the same color.)

[image: periodic function]

$NT$ denotes the integer multiple of $T$ which belongs to the interval $\langle a,a+T \rangle$. (In this example $N=2$.)

---

In case someone wants to see [metapost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetaPost) source for the picture, it is figure 5 from [here](http://msleziak.com/temp/funkcie.mp).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way using the periodicity of the function and the antiderivative:
$$F(x+n\cdot T) = F(x); \ n\in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$
\int^{a+T}_a f(x)dx = F(a+T)-F(a)= F(a) - F(a) = 0 = F(T)-F(0)=\int^T_0 f(x)dx
$$

The periodicity carries over from the function to the antiderivative, which is easily seen if you take a look at the fourier series of the periodic function.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)\ dx&= \int_{T}^{a+T}f(x)\ dx +\int_{a}^{T}f(x)\ dx\\&\overset{y=x-T}{=} \color{red}{\int_{0}^{a}f(y+T)\ dx} +\int_{a}^{T}f(x)\ dx\\&\overset{periodic}{=} \color{red}{\int_{0}^{a}f(y)\ dx} +\int_{a}^{T}f(x)\ dx\\&=\int_0^Tf(x)\ dx.
\end{align}$$