# Integral of periodic function over the length of the period is the same everywhere

Tags: calculus, integration, periodic-functions

I am stuck on a question that involves the intergral of a periodic function. The question is phrased as follows:

> **Definition.** A function is *periodic* with period $a$ if $f(x)=f(x+a)$ for all $x$.
>
> **Question.**
> If $f$ is continuous and periodic with period $a$, then show that $$\int_{0}^{a}f(t)dt=\int_{b}^{b+a}f(t)dt$$
> for all $b\in \mathbb{R}$.

I understand the equality, but I am having trouble showing that it is true for all $b$. I've tried writing it in different forms such as $F(a)=F(b+a)-F(b)$. This led me to the following, though I am not sure how this shows the equality is true for all $b$,

$$\int_{0}^{a}f(t)dt-\int_{b}^{b+a}f(t)dt=0$$
$$=F(a)-F(0)-F(b+a)-F(b)$$
$$=(F(b+a)-F(a))-F(b)$$
$$=\int_{a}^{b+a}f(t)dt-\int_{0}^{b+a}f(t)dt=0$$

So, this leaves me with

$$\int_{a}^{b+a}f(t)dt-\int_{0}^{b+a}f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{a}f(t)dt-\int_{b}^{b+a}f(t)dt$$

I feel I am close, and I've made myself a diagram of a sine function to visualize what each of the above integrals might describe, but the power to explain the above equality evades me.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/94233/5363) for some proofs.

Comment: (Voted to close as duplicate) Even though this says continuous and the other says integrable, the proofs are the same, i.e. every proof here would apply over there.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Let $H(x)=\int_x^{x+a}f(t)\,dt$. Then
$$\frac{dH}{dx}=f(x+a)-f(x)=0.$$ 
It follows that $H(x)$ is constant. In particular, $H(b)=H(0)$.

Answer (score 17):

We have
$$
\int_{0}^{a}f(t)\ dt+\int_{a}^{a+b}f(x)\ dx=\int_{0}^{b}f(y)\ dy+\int_{b}^{a+b}f(t)\ dt,
$$ 
and setting $x=y-a$ turns the second integral into the third one.

Answer (score 11):

$$\begin{align}
\int_{b}^{a+b}f(x)\ dx&= \int_{a}^{a+b}f(x)\ dx +\int_{b}^{a}f(x)\ dx\\&\overset{y=x-a}{=} \color{red}{\int_{0}^{b}f(y+a)\ dx} +\int_{b}^{a}f(x)\ dx\\&\overset{periodic}{=} \color{red}{\int_{0}^{b}f(y)\ dx} +\int_{b}^{a}f(x)\ dx\\&=\int_0^af(x)\ dx.
\end{align}$$

We have used substitution to get from the first to the second equality. We have used the periodicity of the function to get from the second to the third equality.

Comment: The integral is obtained in the second line itself. You have done a calculation mistake.

Comment: Furthermore, this plagiarizes simultaneously **three** other answers, posted six years before.

Answer (score 9):

You have made various false steps in your four line block and should have ended up with $$\int_{a}^{b+a}f(t)dt-\int_{0}^{b}f(t)dt=0$$ but this does not take you much further forward.

Instead note that somewhere in the interval $[b, b+a]$ is an integer multiple of $a$, say $na$.  Then using $f(t)=f(t+a)=f(t+na)$: $$\int_{b}^{b+a}f(t)dt = \int_{b}^{na}f(t)dt+\int_{na}^{b+a}f(t)dt = \int_{b+a}^{(n+1)a}f(t)dt+\int_{an}^{b+a}f(t)dt = \int_{na}^{(n+1)a}f(t)dt = \int_{0}^{a}f(t)dt.$$

Answer (score 8):

*No differentiation is needed:*

Pick the unique integer $n$ such that $b\leqslant na\lt b+a$, decompose the integral of $f(t)$ over $t$ from $b$ to $b+a$ into the sum of the integrals from $b$ to $na$ and from $na$ to $b+a$, apply the changes of variable $t=x+(n-1)a$ in the former and $t=x+na$ in the latter, then the periodicity of $f$ implies that $f(x)=f(t)$, hence the result is the sum of the integrals of $f(x)$ over $x$ from $b-(n-1)a$ to $a$ and from $0$ to $b-(n-1)a$...

*...Et voilà !*