# need to show $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t) dt$ is periodic with period $p$ iff $\int_{0}^{p}f(t)dt=0$

Tags: real-analysis

let $f$ be a continous function on reals with period $p$, we need to show $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t) dt$ is periodic with period $p$ iff $\int_{0}^{p}f(t)dt=0$

well, let $F$ be periodic with period $p$ then $F(x+p)=F(x) \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{x+p}f(t) dt=\int_{0}^{x}f(t) dt$ but I am not getting $\int_{0}^{p}f=0$, applying rolles theorem on $[x,x+p]$ we get $F'(c)=0=f(c)=0$ for some $c\in (x,x+p)$, please help me to solve.

Comment: Note that if $\int_0^p f = 0$, since $f$ is periodic, then $\int_a^{a+p} f = 0$ for any $a$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integral of Periodic Function Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98409/integral-of-periodic-function-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing fine,

$$ F(x+p)=F(x)\quad  \mathrm{iff} \quad\int_{0}^{x+p}f(t) dt=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt + \int_{x}^{x+p}f(t)dt= \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt $$

$$ \mathrm{iff} \quad\int_{x}^{x+p}f(t) dt = 0 \quad  \mathrm{iff} \quad\int_{0}^{p}f(t) dt = 0 .$$

See here for the [last identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98409/integral-of-periodic-function-question).

Answer (score 5):

If $F$ is periodic with period $p$, then $F(0)=F(p)$.

Also, don't forget the other direction of the statement you are trying to prove.

Comment: what an idiot I am, thanku

Answer (score 2):

$F$ is periodic with period $p$ iff $F(x+p) = F(x)$ for all $x$ iff 
$$
\int_{0}^p f(t)dt \left(=\int_{0}^{x+p} f(t) dt -\int_{0}^x f(t) dt = F(x+p)-F(x)\right) = 0.
$$