# A question about variable substitution

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

If $f$ is continuous and $2\pi$-periodic, then $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(y)\,dy=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-y)\,dy$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. In order to verify the identity, first of all, let $y=-y$, we get the following identity
$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(y)\,dy=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(-y)\,dy$, and then we let $y=y-x$,we get the next identity
$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(y)\,dy=\int_{-\pi-x}^{\pi-x}f(x-y)\,dy$. But there is some difference to the right anwer. Can you explain where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your last integral is over an interval of the length of the period ($\pi-x-(-\pi-x)=2\pi$), it is equal to $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x-y) \, dy$ and you're done.

See here: [Integral of periodic function over the length of the period is the same everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98409/integral-of-periodic-function-over-the-length-of-the-period-is-the-same-everywhe) (add $\pi+x$ to both limits of integration to see it clearly.)