# An example for integrable function that is never zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f\::\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be integrable function for all $[a,b],\hspace{0.2cm} (a<b, \hspace{0.5cm}   a,b\in\mathbb{R}$).

and$\hspace{0.2cm}\forall c,x\in\mathbb{R}
\hspace{0.2cm} f(x)\not=0 \hspace{0.2cm}
and \hspace{0.2cm}{\displaystyle \int_{c}^{c+1}f(x)\,dx}=0$

Can I have an example for such function?

Thank you!

Comment: $f(x)=\{1 if x\in[\frac {2k} 2, \frac {2k+1} 2]; -1 if x\in[\frac {2k+1} 2, \frac {2k+2} 2]\}$

Comment: $sin 2\pi x$ should work

Answer (score 3):

You see according to what you say let us take

$f(x)=\sin 2\pi x, \text{ for } x\in\mathbb{R- Z}$

$f(x)=1, \text{ for } x\in\mathbb{ Z}$

$$\int_{a}^{b}\sin 2\pi x \mathrm dx <\infty, \forall a<b$$

And $$\int_{c}^{c+1}\sin 2\pi x \mathrm dx=\int_{0}^{1}\sin 2\pi x \mathrm dx=0, \forall c$$.

Comment: The question also asked for $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) \neq 0$, but $\sin(2\pi 0) = \sin(0) = 0$.

Comment: your answer works you just need to redefine sin where it is 0, to be something else, and it won't change the integral since it is a countable amount of points

Comment: depends which kind of "integrable" he means but yeah

Comment: @ChrisEagle I missed it sorry.

Comment: @BinyaminR Thank you

Comment: Thanks! I have one problem with your answer: if c=pi - is it still correct? I don't quite get it geometrically.

Comment: Yes it is because you see the function is almost periodic . All I mean changing the values at the isolated point won't effect this integral . This function is periodic. I don't know if you have studied measure theory, there is a notion called "measure zero set"( roughly speaking these are the sets of length zero).

Comment: Periodicity ensures the second property .

Comment: @Ludwig Have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98409/779382) as well

Comment: @Ludwig is the answer not worthy to be accepted?