# Prove tha if $f:I\rightarrow\Bbb R$ is a periodic function then $\int_{x}^{x+T}f(t)\,dt=\int_0^T f(t)\,dt$ for any $x\in I$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, proof-explanation, periodic-functions

$$\underline{\text{**ATTENTION**}}$$

**This question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98409/integral-of-periodic-function-over-the-length-of-the-period-is-the-same-everywhe) and [this other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94233/an-integrable-and-periodic-function-fx-satisfies-int-0tfxdx-int-a?noredirect=1&lq=1) question!**

So let be $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ a periodic function, that is there exist $T\in\Bbb R$ such that
$$
f(x+T)=f(x)
$$
for any $x\in \Bbb R$. So I'd like to prove that
$$
\int_x^{x+T}f(t)\,dt=\int_0^Tf(t)\,dt
$$
for any $x\in\Bbb R$ and exactly I'd like to do this using the same arguments that André Nicolas gave in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98409/integral-of-periodic-function-over-the-length-of-the-period-is-the-same-everywhe?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer but now I'd like do this with more details since I am sure that the mentioned user proves the result using the *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus* but unfortunately it is not clear how he applies it so that I thought to pay an apposite question where I ask to give this proof adding more details, that's all. Moreover it seems to me that if the period $T$ of $f$ is negative then the above integral could not be defined so that I ask also clarification about this.

So could anyone help me, please?

Comment: It is not generally true that $\int_T^{x+T} g(t)\,dt=\int_0^T g(s)\,ds$.

Comment: Sure, I know this...

Comment: And yet you claim that it is.  All change of variables gets you is $\int_T^{x+T} g(t)\,dt=\int_0^T g(s+T)\,ds$

Comment: No, I said that the result is very stranger! So I do not say what you claim.

Comment: Yes, you did.   Right after " so that by the change variables theorem it follows that"

Comment: I wrote this **before** to say that the result is illogical so that I think it does not have sense: anyway if you like I can edit the question.

Comment: What you wrote is false, no matter what the reason you wrote it.  I did not read beyond that error.

Comment: Okay, anyway I edited the question: I hope now it is more clear. Sorry, for the wrong.

Comment: Post edit, the false claim is still present.

Comment: Just take some non-periodic function, like $f(z)=z$, and go through your steps with that function to see that your argument fails.

Comment: The thing is that you actually do use the periodicity of $g$ in your proof, in the line that lulu points out. $\int_T^{x + T} g(t) dt = \int_0^x g(s+T) ds,$ and because $g(s + T) = g(s)$ for our periodic function we can rewrite as $\int_0^x g(s) ds,$ from which the rest of your argument can proceed.

Comment: @lulu I repeate I know that the result is false: I put only it so that the people could see how I tried to prove the statement and so hoping that the proof can be adjusted and thus I cannot elimitate it, that's all. Sorry.

Comment: Once again:  I have identified the line in your argument that is false for general functions.  Of course, that line holds if you use periodicity.  Not sure what else there is to say.

Comment: @lulu Okay, I understand what you want say: the problem is that I do not how apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to the function $\int_0^xg(s+T)\,ds$, that's all. So could you explain this rigorously?

Comment: You can still apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to that integral, but the result you would get is now $g(x + T),$ so you get $G'(x) = g(x+T) - g(x),$ which is not zero in general unless we have $g(x + T) = g(x).$

Comment: I don't understand.  Your argument uses periodicity, of course.  Periodicity tells you that $g(s+T)=g(s)$.  Without periodicity, you can not advance your argument.  So...what are you trying to do?

Comment: You ask where the wrong is, but it's been said:  you claimed not to use the periodicity of $g$, but you actually did.

Comment: @StephenDonovan So if I understood I have to put $$\gamma(s):=g(s+T)$$ so that $$\frac d{dx}\int_0^xg(s+T)\,ds=\frac d{dx}\int_0^x\gamma(s)\,ds=\gamma(x)=g(x+T)$$ right?

Comment: I believe that would be the correct way to write it out more fully, yes.

Comment: @Randall So first I pretended ** intentionally ** a uncorrect proof: I know that it is uncorrect because I claim explicitly that the result is false, okay? So I asked where is the wrong in the proof. Then I presented a good proof and I asked a clarification about it. Where is the problem? What did I do wrong? How I should have express my difficulties?

Comment: @StephenDonovan Oaky, so where's the problem in the first proof? that is, why without the periodicity of $g$ I can not apply the fundamental theorem of calculus? I'd like to know it because this can be usefull for the future: learning from your mistakes is good.

Comment: So again, you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus, but it doesn't yield a useful result. When you continue your proof with that result, you would arrive at $G'(x) = g(x + T) - g(x),$ which is not zero in general, but only if we assume $g(x + T) = g(x).$ So if we don't assume periodicity then we don't get that $G' = 0$ and we don't get $G(x) = G(0),$ which is the crux of the entire argument.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Sorry, but I do not understand very well. So using the change of variable formula I proved that $$\int_T^{x+T}g(t)\,dt=\int_0^Tg(s)\,ds$$ (IS THIS ALWAYS TRUE?) then it would be $$G(x)=\int_0^xg(s)\,ds-\int_T^xg(t)\,dt$$ and  so applying the fundamentel theorem (IS THIS POSSIBLE?) then we discover that $G$ is costant but this is false: so where I get a mistake? I get a mistake using the change variables or the fundamental theorem? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: Here your mistake is in the change of variables, as discussed before. In the first line the correct integrand for the right-hand side is $g(s + T),$ which we can only change to $g(s)$ if we assume periodicity. Continuing after this correction would lead to the problem I mentioned in that last comment.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Oh yeah!!! indeed if $s=t-T$ then necessary $t=s+T$ so that the change variable formula implies that $$\int_{[T,x+T]}g(t)\,dt=\int_{\varphi^{-1}\big[[T,x+T]\big]}g(t(s))\,ds=\int_{[0,T]}g(s+T)$$ right?

Comment: That looks correct to me, yes.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Okay, now it is all clear: so thanks very much for your assistance!!! You was really kind with me, so thanks yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we observe that the period $T$ can be suppose not negative without loss of generality: indeed if $T$ was not positive then $-T$ would be not negative and it would be such that
$$
f(x-T)=f\big((x-T)+T\big)=f(x)
$$
for any $x\in\Bbb R$. So without loss of generality we can suppose that
$$
x\le x+T
$$
for any $x\in\Bbb R$ so that the function $F:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$  defined as
$$
F(x):=\int_x^{x+T}f(t)\,dt
$$
for any $x\in\Bbb R$ is well defined.

So we let to prove now that $F$ is constant and precisely we are doing this proving that it is constant in $(-\infty,T]$ and in $[T,+\infty)$ respectively.

Previously we remember that the *Change of Variables Theorem* states that

> Given a diffeomorphism $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ between open sets of $\Bbb R^n$ for any $C^r$ function $f:A\rightarrow\Bbb R$ with $r\ge 1$ the identity $$\int_Af=\int_B(f\circ \phi)|\det Dg|$$ holds.

whereas the *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus* states that

> If $I$ is a (closed) interval of the real line $\Bbb R$ with extremities $x_1$ and $x_2$ then given a real valued function $f:I\rightarrow\Bbb R$ the function $F:I\rightarrow\Bbb R$ defined as
> $$
> F(x):=\int_{[x_1,x]}f(\xi)\,d\xi
> $$
> for any $x\in I$ is derivable in $I$ and it is such that
> $$
> \operatorname{D}F(x)=f(x)
> $$
> for any $x\in I$.

1. So let be now $x\in(T+\infty]$ and thus through the additivity of the integral we observe that
   $$
   F(x):=\int_{[x,x+T]}f(t)\,dt=\int_{[T,x+T]\setminus[T,x]}f(t)\,dt=\int_{[T,x+T]}f(t)\,dt-\int_{[T,x]}f(t)\,dt
   $$
   for any $x\in[T,+\infty)$. Now let be $\varphi:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ the diffeomorphism defined through the equation
   $$
   \varphi(x):=x+T
   $$
   for any $x\in\Bbb R$. So through the *Chain Rule* we conclude that
   $$
   \operatorname{D}F(x)=D\Biggl[\int_{\big[T,\varphi(x)\big]}f(t)\,dt-\int_{[T,x]}f(t)\,dt\Biggl]=\\
   \operatorname{D}\Biggl[\int_{\big[T,\varphi(x)\big]}f(t)\,dt\Biggl]\cdot\operatorname{D}\varphi(x)-\operatorname{D}\Biggl[\int_{[T,x]}f(t)\,dt\Biggl]=\\
   f\big(\varphi(x)\big)-f(x)=f(x+T)-f(x)=0
   $$
   for any $x\in[T,+\infty)$ and so the statement is proved for this such $x$.
2. So let be now $x\in(-\infty,T]$ and provided that $x$ is not negative through the additivity of the integral we observe that
   $$
   F(x):=\int_{[x,x+T]}f(t)\,dt=\int_{[x,T]\cup[T,x+t]}f(t)\,dt=\int_{[x,T]}f(t)\,dt+\int_{[T,x+T]}f(t)\,dt
   $$
   Now let be $\phi:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ the diffeomorphism defined through the equation
   $$
   \phi(x):=-x
   $$
   for any $x\in\Bbb R$ so that through the change variables theorem we conclude that
   $$
   F(x)=\int_{[x,T]}f(t)\,dt+\int_{[T,x+T]}f(t)\,dt=\int_{(x,T)}f(t)\,dt+\int_{(T,x+T)}f(t)\,dt=\\
   \int_{\phi^{-1}\big[(x,T)\big]}\big(f\circ\phi\big)(t)\cdot\Big|\operatorname{det}\big(\operatorname{D}\phi(t)\big)\Big|\,dt+\int_{\big(x,\varphi(x)\big)}f(t)dt=\\
   \int_{(-T,-x)}\big(f\circ\phi\big)(t)\,dt+\int_{\big(T,\varphi(x)\big)}f(t)\,dt=\int_{\big(-T,\phi(x)\big)}\big(f\circ\phi\big)(t)\,dt+\int_{\big(T,\varphi(x)\big)}f(t)\,dt
   $$
   for any $x\in[0,T]$ and thus finally through the *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus* and through the *Chain Rule* we conclude that
   $$
   \operatorname{D}F(x)=
   \operatorname{D}\Biggl[\int_{\big(-T,\phi(x)\big)}\big(f\circ\phi\big)(t)\,dt+\int_{\big(T,\varphi(x)\big)}f(t)\,dt\Biggl]=\\
   D\Biggl[\int_{\big(-T,\phi(x)\big)}\big(f\circ\phi\big)(t)\,dt\Biggl]\cdot\operatorname{D}\phi(x)+\operatorname{D}\Biggl[\int_{\big((T,\varphi(x)\big)}f(t)\,dt\Biggl]\cdot\operatorname{D}\varphi(x)=\\
   -\Big(f\circ\phi\Big)\big(\phi(x)\big)+f\big(\varphi(x)\big)=f\big(\varphi(x)\big)-f\Big(\phi\big(\phi(x)\big)\Big)=f(x+T)-f(x)=0
   $$
   for any $x\in[0,T]$ so that we proved that $F$ is effectively constant on the not negative real line. Whereas if $x$ is not positive through the additivity of the integral we observe that
   $$
   F(x):=\int_{[x,x+T]}f(t)\,dt=\int_{[x,T]\setminus[x+T,x]}f(t)\,dt=\int_{[x+T]}f(t)\,dt-\int_{[x+T,x]}f(t)\,dt
   $$
   for any $x\in(-\infty,0]$ so that through the change variables theorem we conclude that
   $$
   F(x)=\int_{[x,T]}f(t)\,dt-\int_{[x+T,T]}f(t)\,dt=\\
   \int_{\phi^{-1}\big[[x,T]\big]}(f\circ\phi)(t)\,dt-\int_{\phi^{-1}\big[[x+T,T]\big]}(f\circ\phi)(t)\,dt=\\
   \int_{[-T,-x]}(f\circ\phi)(t)\,dt-\int_{[-T,-(x+T)]}(f\circ\phi)(t)\,dt
   $$
   for any $x\in(-\infty,0]$ and thus finally through the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and through the Chain Rule we conclude that
   $$
   DF(x)=D\Biggl[\int_{[-T,-x]}(f\circ\phi)(t)\,dt-\int_{[-T,-(x+T)]}(f\circ\phi)(t)\,dt\Biggl]=\\
   D\Biggl[\int_{[-T,\phi(x)]}(f\circ\phi)(t)\,dt-\int_{[-T,(\phi\circ\varphi)(x)]}(f\circ\phi)(t)\,dt\Biggl]=\\
   D\Biggl[\int_{[-T,\phi(x)]}(f\circ\phi)(t)\,dt\Biggl]\cdot D\phi(x)-D\Biggl[\int_{[-T,(\phi\circ\varphi)(x)]}(f\circ\phi)(t)\,dt\Biggl]\cdot D(\phi\circ\varphi)(x)=\\
   -(f\circ\phi)(\phi(x))-\Big(-(f\circ\phi)\Big(\big(\phi\circ\varphi\big)(x)\Big)\Big)=\\
   f\big(\varphi(x)\big)-f(x)=f(x+T)-f(x)=0
   $$
   for any $x\in(-\infty,0]$ and this proves finally that $F$ is constant in $(-\infty,0]$ too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need advance technique. In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{x}^{x+T}g(t)\,dt&=&\int_0^{x+T} g(t)\,dt-\int_0^{x} g(t)\,dt\\
&=&\int_{-T}^{x} g(u+T)\,dt-\int_0^{x} g(t)\,dt\\
&=&\int_{-T}^0g(t)\,dt=\int_{0}^Tg(T+t)\,dt\\
&=&\int_{0}^Tg(t)\,dt.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Unfortunately there is a little problem: in the proof I implicitly assumed that $x\ge T$ since otherwise it was not possible to break the integral and analogous thing you do assuming that $x\ge0$. Anyway without loss of generality we can assume that $T\ge0$ so that my proof show that the result is true for $x\le 0$ and it seems that you do the **same*. So what can you say about? Indeed I did not observe initially this.

Comment: Pheraps I found a rigorous answer as you can see below: so what do you think about it? is it correct?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro $x$ can be any value.

Comment: Sorry, but inf you write $$\int_x^{x+T}g(t)\,dt=\int_0^{x+T}g(t)\,dt-\int_0^xg(t)\,dt$$ indeed necessarly it must by $x>0$ because otherwise it would be $$\int_x^{x+T}g(t)\,dt=\int_x^0g(t)\,dt+\int_0^{x+T}g(t)\,dt$$ and so by the change variable formula putting $$\varphi(x):=-x$$ you could write $$\int_x^{x+T}g(t)\,=\int_x^0g(t)\,dt+\int_0^{x+T}g(t)\,dt=\int_{\varphi^{-1}\big[(x,0)\big]}g\big(\varphi(t)\big)\,dt+\int_0^{x+T}g(t)\,dt$$ right? So where's my wrong? Excuse me for the confusion.

Comment: So substantially the problem is that for me the identity $$\int_a^b f(x)$$ has no meaning when $b<a$ because by definition $$\int_a^bf(x):=\int_{(a,b)}f(x)$$ that's all.

Comment: If $a>b$, the integral $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ is interpreted as $-\int_b^af(x)dx$.

Comment: Okay, but it is only a convention, right? In other words, are there some **FORMAL AND RIGOROUS** results that can attribute a meaning to $\int_b^a(x) dx$?

Comment: Pheraps this can be done by inverting the usual order of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Your answer is nothing wrong. It is just too long.

Comment: I think it is long exactly because I did not define $\int_b^a f(x), dx$, that's all.