# Proving a function defined as the integral of another function is well defined

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have $2\pi$ periodic function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that is integrable on $[0,2\pi]$ where it holds that $\int^{2\pi}_0 f(x) dx = 0$ Define this function $$h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}:h(t) = \int^t_0 f(x) dx. $$ How can we see that $h$ is well defined? Usually it seems quite obvious how to prove "well-definedness" but I'm a bit confused here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: perhaps the author is asking if it is well defined because f is integrable only on $[0,2\pi]$, but using the fact that it is periodic, it must be integrable on any interval.

Comment: @Ilovemath hmm I'm still not entirely convinced

Comment: add a answer! I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example, write $t=t_0+2k\pi$, with $t_0 \in [0,2\pi]$ then

$$h(t) = \int_0^{t_0+2k\pi}f(x)dx  = \int_0^{t_0}f(x)dx+\int_{t_0}^{t_0+2\pi}f(x)dx+ \cdots+\int_{t_0+2(k-1)\pi}^{[t_0+2(k-1)\pi]+2\pi}f(x)dx$$
successively use this result
[enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98409/integral-of-periodic-function-over-the-length-of-the-period-is-the-same-everywhe/2608155).

With this result, all that matters is the fact that $\int_0^{t_0}f(x)dx$ exists.

Comment: so this expression for $h(t)$ just reduces to the first term on the right?

Comment: yes, and $f$ is integrable in $[0, t_0] \subset [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: awesome! thanks

Comment: You're welcome!