# To show $\int_{-\pi+x}^{\pi+x}f(u) du=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(u) du$.

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An integrable and periodic function $f(x)$  satisfies $\int_{0}^{T}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)dx$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94233/an-integrable-and-periodic-function-fx-satisfies-int-0tfxdx-int)

I have to show if $f\in \mathcal L[-\pi,\pi]$ and if $$f(u+2\pi)=f(u), (-\infty<u<\infty),$$
then, for any real $x$,
$$\int_{-\pi+x}^{\pi+x}f(u) du=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(u) du.$$
I am approaching the answer of this question in the following manner,
$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(u) du=\int_{-\pi}^{-\pi+x}f(u)du+\int_{-\pi+x}^{\pi}f(u)du= I_{1}+I_{2}.\tag{1}$$
Now,
$$I_{1}=\int_{-\pi}^{-\pi+x}f(u)du$$
Taking $u=t-2\pi$, we get,
$$I_{1}=\int_{\pi}^{\pi+x}f(t-2\pi) dt=\int_{\pi}^{\pi+x}f(t)dt. (\because f\ \text{is periodic})$$
Thus,
$$I_{1}=\int_{\pi}^{\pi+x}f(t) dt.$$
From $(1)$, we get,
$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(u)du=\int_{\pi}^{\pi+x}f(u)du+\int_{-\pi+x}^{\pi}f(u)du=\int_{-\pi+x}^{\pi+x}f(u)du.$$
Am i approach right?

Comment: This is basically the same question as: [An integrable and periodic function $f(x)$  satisfies $\int_{0}^{T}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)dx$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94233/an-integrable-and-periodic-function-fx-satisfies-int-0tfxdx-int)

Comment: I don't know that this question already asked! Sorry for that! But you can tell me am i justify the answer of this question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct and pretty nice, indeed.