# Fejer Kernel problem

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

I encountered this in my notes:

$$\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathcal{F}(f- f')df = 1\;\;\;\;\;\;\forall\;f'\;\;\;(1)$$
where
$$\mathcal{F}(f) = \frac{\sin^2(N\pi f)}{N\sin^2(\pi f)}.$$

I know that 
$$\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathcal{F}(f)df = 1.$$

But I do not know how $(1)$ comes about. How do you show $(1)$ gives you $1$. Please give me a hand here please.

Answer (score 1):

As Féjer's kernel is periodic of period $1$ and integrable on bounded sets (as a bounded function), the result follows from [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94233/an-integrable-and-periodic-function-fx-satisfies-int-0tfxdx-int).

Comment: This is really a comment because it's not an answer: although it points out that the integral is invariant with respect to $f'$, it still leaves the O.P. with the problem of finding that constant ("show (1) gives you $1$").