# In deriving $\int_{0}^{T}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)dx$, why doesn't this imply $f$ is constant?

Tags: integration, periodic-functions

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this, if f(x) is a periodic function with period T then it satisfies $$\int_{0}^{T}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)\;dx$$ for all $a \in \Bbb R$. It is clear that this must be true, but if you differentiate both sides with respect to $T$ do you not get $$f(T)=f(T+a)$$ and so because $$f(T+a)=f(a)$$ this implies that $$f(T)=f(a)$$ for all $a \in \Bbb R$, but does this not imply $f$ is constant? I am struggling to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: The relation holds only if T is a period of f, not for arbitrary T. Therefore you cannot differentiate with respect to T.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94233/an-integrable-and-periodic-function-fx-satisfies-int-0tfxdx-int-a)

Answer (score 1):

The equality $\int_{0}^{T}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)dx$ holds for
all $a \in \Bbb R$, but only for values $T$ which are a *period*
of $f$.

The derivative is only defined for functions defined on an *interval*.
So what you actually have proved is that if the set of periods
contains an open interval then $f$ is constant.