# The convolution theorem for fourier series.:$ \widehat{f*g}(x) =2π\hat{g}(x)\cdot\hat{f}(x) $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I saw this theorem in Wikipedia, and didn't see it in other place. I tried to proof it, but failed.

> How to prove that for $2\pi-$periodic functions one has The convolution theorem for fourier series.:
>   $$ \widehat{f*g}(x) =2π\hat{g}(x)\cdot\hat{f}(x) $$
>   **Note: this is convolution theorem for fourier series, not transforms**

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upVMJ.png)

Comment: Is there a question you wanted us to answer?

Comment: A proof of this is in nearly every book / lecture notes on fourier analysis

Comment: note, this theorem is for fourier series, not fourier transform.
I tried to find a proof on the web, and I didn't find even the theorem itself on other sources.

Comment: @JohnHughes
It will be nice to see a proof to this theorem.

Comment: Of *what* theorem? You've shown us a proof of a theorem that isn't the one you care about (apparently). If you could carefully state the theorem whose proof you'd *like* to see, perhaps we could help you. As @TheWaveLad says, it's almost certainly in any book you pick up, but we could actually tell you the theorem NUMBER in a book or two ...

Comment: @JohnHughes,
I don't know what you are talking about. have you seen the photo I uploaded? it's a copy from wikipedia.
it states a theorem for **fourier series** of a convolution. it's not a proof.

Comment: **Hint**: 
$$4 \pi^2 \hat f(n) \hat g(n) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{-inx} \mathrm dx \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(y)e^{-iny} \mathrm dy = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-int} \left( \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)g(t-x) \mathrm dx \right)\mathrm dt $$

Comment: @ClementC. this is about Fourier series not Fourrier transform. have a close look to see that it is not that obvious  and similar. so this is clearly not a duplicate

Comment: @GuyFsone My bad, I got the suggestion from the review queue and failed to look closely enough. Thank you.

Comment: @ClementC. me too I got it from the review queues buit....

Comment: @ClementC.  you may have look the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The proof use the same token as in the case of Fourier transform.
>   Indeed, $f$ and $g$ be $2\pi$-periodic functions. But since the function $y\mapsto e^{-iyx}g(y)$ is $2π-$periodic, then [using this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2608144) we have , 
>   $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-ix(t-u)}g(t-u)dt\overset{y=t-u}{=} \color{blue}{\int_{-u}^{2\pi-u} e^{-ixy}g(y)dy =\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-ixy}g(y)dy}= 2π\hat{g}(x) $$

Inserting this in the following  relation we get

$$ \color{blue}{\widehat{f*g}(x) =}  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-ixt}f*g(t)dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-ixt}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(u)g(t-u)dudt\\=
 \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(e^{-iux}f(u)\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-ix(t-u)}g(t-u)dt\right)du\\= 2π\hat{g}(x) \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-iux}f(u)du= \color{red}{2π\widehat{g}(x)\cdot\widehat{f}(x)} $$

we used this [An integrable and periodic function $f(x)$ satisfies $\int_{0}^{T}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)dx$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94233/an-integrable-and-periodic-function-fx-satisfies-int-0tfxdx-int-a)