# A function which is periodic and integrable

Tags: calculus, integration, periodic-functions

Suppose $f(x)$ is periodic with period $l$ and integrable. Prove that, for any a,

$\int_{0}^{l}$$f(x+a)$dx = $\int_{0}^{l}$$f(x)$dx

I tried to change the values and define y=a+x so that dy=dx and the limits of the integrals are as we want.

Comment: [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94233/an-integrable-and-periodic-function-fx-satisfies-int-0tfxdx-int-a?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1)
Use the fact that 
$$\int_{a}^{a+l}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{l}f(x)dx  + \int_{l}^{l+a}f(x)dx$$
Now use the periodicity with $l$ to get 
$$\int_{l}^{l+a}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{0+a}f(x+l)dx=\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$$

Altogether 
$$\int_{a}^{a+l}f(x)dx =\int_{a}^{l}f(x)dx  + \int_{l}^{l+a}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{l}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{l}f(x)dx$$

For 2)
Use the substitution $y=x+a$ to get
$$\int_{0}^{l}f(x+a)dx = \int_{a}^{a+l}f(y)dy $$
Now you have a form that behaves exactly as the start of 1). Repeating the complete procedure again will lead to the same result, thus
$$\int_{0}^{l}f(x+a)dx = \int_{0}^{l}f(y)dy $$

Comment: For the second I found:

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if you are happy with it to show other people that this question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

For the second I found:

$\int_{0}^{l}$$f(x+a)$dx = $\int_{0}^{l}$$f(x)$dx

$\int_{0}^{l}$$f(x+a)$dx $-$ $\int_{0}^{l}$$f(x)$dx = $\int_{0}^{l}$$f(x+a)-f(x)$dx = $\int_{0}^{l}$$0$dx = $0$

Comment: Unfortunately that is not correct. $f(x+a)\neq f(x)$. You only have periodicity with $l$, not with $a$!

Comment: Could you maybe help me with this one as well?

Comment: Use the substitution $y=a+x$ as you described as your own idea and rewrite part 2) to a version that will look exactly like part 1). Then the proof is as before.

Comment: It seems stupid but I still can't get the right answer after using different substitutions.

Comment: I edited my solution to show part 2). Glad to see you took the effort to try yourself!

Comment: Thankyou very much, I forgot to use the substitution in the upper and lower bound